# Java - Listen to variable change

Tags: java, global-variables, actionlistener

First of all i am brand new to Java : /

I have been trying to solve this problem on my own for about 2 days now but cant get around it the problem is i am trying to implement a variable change listener. I have tried without successes to implement Observer and Observable to my project but whit no successes at best i came up by wrapping some elements of the code in to while loops but that well fails.

Any how this is my class and if you look at it i have some global variables defined after the constructor i need to listen for a change in all of those global variables if one changes i would like to execute a method.

I have been told JavaFX has methods that can listen to variables can someone confirm this.
Anyhow thanks for help in advance.

```
public class Tower_Controller {

    public Tower_Controller() {
    }

    //Global variables
    String isSelected = null;
    int hasModules = 0;
    int cap_s = 0;
    int cpu_s = 0;
    int cap = 0;
    int cpu = 0;
    int shield = 0;
    int armor = 0;
    double em = 00.00;
    double th = 00.00;
    double ki = 00.00;
    double ex = 00.00;


    public void invoke() {
        Invoke_GUI runnable = new Invoke_GUI();
        final JLabel tower_name = runnable.tower_name;
        final JComboBox tower_select = runnable.tower_select;
        final JTree module_browser = runnable.module_browser;
        final JTree selected_modules = runnable.selected_modules;

        final JProgressBar cap_bar = runnable.cap_bar;
        final JProgressBar cpu_bar = runnable.cpu_bar;

        final JLabel em_res = runnable.em;
        final JLabel th_res = runnable.thermic;
        final JLabel ki_res = runnable.kinetic;
        final JLabel ex_res = runnable.explosive;

        tower_select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isSelected != null) {
                    Events evt = new Events();
                    evt.towerSelected(isSelected);
                } else {
                    tower_name.setText(tower_select.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    isSelected = tower_name.toString();
                }
            }
        });

        removeTower(tower_name);
        runnable.setVisible(true);

    }



    public void updateValues(final JProgressBar cap_bar, final JProgressBar cpu_bar, final JLabel em_res,
        final JLabel th_res, final JLabel ki_res, final JLabel ex_res){

        cap_bar.setMaximum(cap);
        cap_bar.setString(cap_s + " / " + cap);
        cap_bar.setStringPainted(true);

        cpu_bar.setMaximum(cpu);
        cpu_bar.setString(cpu_s + " / " + cpu);
        cpu_bar.setStringPainted(true);

        String em_v = String.valueOf(em); 
        em_res.setText(em_v);

        String th_v = String.valueOf(th); 
        th_res.setText(th_v);

        String ki_v = String.valueOf(ki); 
        ki_res.setText(ki_v);

        String ex_v = String.valueOf(ex); 
        ex_res.setText(ex_v);
    }

    public void updateList(final ArrayList<String> nodes, final JTree selected_modules) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode nod = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            nod.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodes.get(i)));
        }
        selected_modules.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(nod));
    }

    public void removeTower(final JLabel tower_name) {
        tower_name.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (hasModules == 1 & isSelected != null) {
                    Events evt = new Events();
                    evt.towerHasModules();
                } else if (isSelected == null) {
                } else {
                    tower_name.setText("No Control Tower selected");
                    isSelected = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    public JLabel setTowerName(JLabel a, String name) {
        a.setText(name);
        return a;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The general procedure to be notified of a change to a variable is as follows:

1. First, *make the variables private.*
2. Create two methods for each variable, one which sets its value to an argument (often called `setX()`, where `X` is the variable name), the other which retrieves its value (`getX()`)
3. Everywhere you need to read or set the variable, call the methods instead.
4. In the `setX()` method, call `notifyObserver()` on your `Observer`s, in a loop.

And there you go! Now every time the variable is changed, registered `Observer`s are notified. The key part of this solution is that the variables have to be private, so that no code can set their values without going through the `setX()` methods.

Comment: Yeah, PropertyChangeListener works fine too, and you can use PropertyChangeSupport to notify the listeners. He specifically mentioned Observer/Observable, though.

Comment: Huh. Well, my instructions above seem pretty clear and simple. Is there anything I can do to improve them? What problems or questions do you have?